# Java Web Start(FailedDownloadException)

Tags: java, java-web-start

When I try to start my java web start app i got this error:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/blog/WebStartApp.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.downloadResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

sample.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
      codebase="http://localhost:8080/blog/" 
      href="sample.jnlp">
   <information>
      <title>Sample JWS application</title>
      <vendor>JBoss tutorials</vendor>
      <description>JWS on JBoss Demo</description>
   </information>
   <secruity>
    <all-permissions/>
   </secruity>
   <resources>     
       <jar href="WebStartApp.jar"/>   
    <j2se version="1.6.10+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>
   </resources>
   <application-desc main-class="webStartClasses.App"/>
</jnlp>
```

Jnlp and jar files are placed in .war file which is deployed on JBoss server

How fix this ?

Comment: If you put `http://localhost:8080/blog/WebStartApp.jar` in the address bar of the browser and hit 'Enter', does the server provide the Jar to you?

Answer (score 3):

You spelled security wrong, you said secruity.